# Unable to retrieve JSON response in Apache JMeter

Tags: java, json, serialization, jmeter

I have been trying to test a webservice in Apache Jmeter. The webservice returns JSON in response. But I am getting the following error as response in "View Result in Tree" section-

> System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error generating the
>   XML document. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The type
>   package.name.CustomResponse was not expected. Use the XmlInclude or
>   SoapInclude attribute to specify types that are not known statically.
>          at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriter1.Write7_JsonResult(String
>   n, String ns, JsonResult o, Boolean isNullable, Boolean needType)
>          at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriter1.Write41_JsonResult(Object
>   o)
>          at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(XmlWriter xmlWriter, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces, String
>   encodingStyle, String id)
>          --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>          at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(XmlWriter xmlWriter, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces, String
>   encodingStyle, String id)
>          at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(TextWriter textWriter, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces)
>          at System.Web.Services.Protocols.XmlReturnWriter.Write(HttpResponse
>   response, Stream outputStream, Object returnValue)
>          at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.WriteReturns(Object[]
>   returnValues)
>          at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.Invoke()

The same webservice works properly in Android application. Do I need to deserialize the JSON? If so, how can we deserialize JSON response in JMeter?  What could be the reason of this? Please help!

Comment: It looks like the server is sending an error. Have you tried to check the request you are sending?

Comment: Yes. It is perfectly working in android app but doesn't work in browser. It displays the same error when I run it from chrome/firefox.

Comment: Dawid Pura is right: you  are getting server-side error, and most likely it's because you are sending the request not exactly the way the server is expecting it. One big clue to that is _Microsoft.Xml..._ - JMeter doesn't use any MS libraries. So looks to me that you found a bug (even if request is not right, sending such exception back is not the best response).

Comment: @JohnC could you share an details of this request? It would be better to investigate.